# How to skip the first line of a file?

Tags: java, file

I read from file and stored in array, and the first line of the file contains only "1" and from second line it contains a dictionary words splitting from the space bar. So how can I read the file from the second line?

```
try
        {
         File text = new File ("dictionary.txt");
         Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("dictionary.txt"));

         while(file.hasNextLine())
         {
          System.out.println("Level 1");
           int level1 = file.nextInt();
           file.nextLine();



           for(int i = 1; i < 7; i++)
            {
             String [] array = content.split(" ");

             String A = array[0];
             String B = array[1];
             String C = array[2];

            System.out.println(B);
           }
         }
         file.close();
        }
```

the format of the file is

1

ant yes bag who and car cry do zoo dog ear
my mum eat are eye fat dad win fun go get

Comment: You could add a counter variable to count which line number you're on and when counter == 1 (assuming you start at 1) use `continue` to go to the next iteration of your loop. If you don't think it's useful to have the line number any other time you could just use a boolean instead.

Comment: Err, read it? Before the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a counter

```
int count = 0;
while(file.hasNextLine())
{
    count++;
    if (count <= 1) {
      file.nextLine ();
      continue;
    }
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would actually use `text` instead of redefining the `File` to construct the `Scanner`. Prefer `try-with-Resources` to explicitly closing the `Scanner`. Actually assign `content`, don't hard-code "magic values" for array iteration. Basically, something like

```
File text = new File("dictionary.txt");
try (Scanner file = new Scanner(text)) {
    if (file.hasNextLine()) {
        file.nextLine(); // skip first line.
    }
    while (file.hasNextLine()) {
        String content = file.nextLine();
        if (content.isEmpty()) {
            continue; // skip empty lines
        }
        String[] array = content.split("\\s+");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(array[i]);
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Another option, if using Java 8+, is to use `Files.lines(Path)` to stream all of the lines (and `skip(1)`) like

```
File text = new File("dictionary.txt");
try {
    Files.lines(text.toPath()).skip(1).forEach(content -> {
        if (!content.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(content.split("\\s+")));
        }
    });
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```